# Does abstracting an entity using an interface somehow break usage of where-clauses?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So I have an entitytype called SportsWagon and an interface ICar that SportsWagon implements. I've also created a function of type `IEnumerable<ICar> GetCars(Func<ICar, bool> filter)` that fetches the matching cars from the SportsWagons and returns them as an enumerable of cars. This function is very simple and only calls `MyContext.SportsWagons.Where(filter).Where(someAdditionalLogicInSomeCases);`

My problem is that, using SQL Profiler, the queries generated by this seem to be completely missing the WHERE-clause. What's worse, is that if I have a loop that fetches same cars multiple times, they seem to generate a new query every time. I'm using EF 4.3.1 database first. So is EF just unable to translate the interface-based Func to create the correct query with the database, or am I just doing something else that's totally silly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've also created a function ... `filter` that ...
>   ..`.Where(filter).`...

EF cannot translate a function to SQL. You'll have to provide a lambda.

To make sure, post the relevant code for how the function and the query fit together.

Comment: Hmm interesting. I actually never bothered figuring out the different between an Expression<Func<T, TResult>> and just a Func<T, TResult>. But as it turns out, changing the parameter to the former one was enough in my case. So while technically not a solution to my problem, your answer did guide me towards the solutions. Thanks for that!